# How to use Verdana Font in Stamper (iText PDF)

Tags: pdf, itext

I want to use Verdana as a font while stamping a PDF file with iText PDF. The original file uses Verdana, which isn't an option in the class Basefont.

Here is the function to create my font right now:

```
def standardStampFont() {
    return BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, false)
}
```

I'd like to change that to the Verdana Font, but simply exchanging the Part `BaseFont.HELVETICA` with `"Verdana"` doesn't work.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented, iText supports the Standard Type 1 fonts, because iText ships with AFM file (Adobe Font Metrics files). iText has no idea about the font metrics of other fonts (Verdana isn't a Standard Type 1 font). You need to provide the path to the Verdana font file.

```
BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/verdana.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
```

Note that I change `false` to `BaseFont.EMBEDDED` because the same problem you have on your side, will also occur on the side of the person who looks at your file: his PDF viewer can render Standard Type 1 fonts, but may not be able to render other fonts such as Verdana.

**Caveat:** The hard coded path `"c:/windows/fonts/verdana.ttf"` works for me on my local machine because the font file can be found using that path on my local machine. This code won't work on the server where I host the iText site, though (which is a Linux server that doesn't even have a `c:/windows/fonts` directory). I am using this hard coded path by way of example. You should make sure that the font is present and available when you deploy your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the tip regarding the embedded part. I have to change the path indeed, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line makes sure the FontFactory actually registers the fonts in the operating systems' default fonts directories:

```
FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();
```

After that all the installed fonts can be found using something like

```
var myfont = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 10f, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
```

I get that this post is old, but it's still relevant I guess.